# Probability of choosing

Tags: probability

A problem from my book ask the following question:

a 3-digit number $\#(000-999)$ is chosen at random, what is the probability that exactly one digit will be $>5$.

The answer from the back of the book is $.432$

Now this is what I have and know so far.

$$P(A)= \frac{\text{Total outcomes for }A}{\text{Total possible outcomes }\Omega}$$

I figured that my sample space is $1000$, because there are three digit each of which can be filled in with $0-9$. so $10^3 = 1000$

Now I am having trouble finding the total outcomes for $A$(myevent). 
my attempts were the following:

_(the first digit can be $0-4$) _(the second can be $5-9$) _(the third can be ($5-9$) but since they can be arranged in any order I get $5^3\times3=375$

so $375/1000= .375$, which is obviously wrong, I've tried a few other ways but each one does not get me the correct answer.

Comment: Only 6,7,8 and 9 are greater than 5 so beware of how many possibilities exist for each spot is the part that you are missing I suspect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Pick whether the *large* digit is in the first space, the second space, or the third space. $3$ options
- Pick what the large digit is (*it can be any of 6,7,8 or 9*): $4$ options
- From left to right, pick the remaining digits (*can be any of 0,1,2,3,4,5*)$6\cdot 6$ options

There are then $3\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 6=432$ possible length three digit strings with exactly one digit greater than $5$.

The probability then is $\frac{432}{1000}$

Comment: Okay I understand the 3*4 part, but why 6*6, the question is asking for exactly one digit less than 5

Comment: @learnmore exactly one digit will be *greater* than $5$ and the remaining *two* digits then will be *less than or equal* to $5$.

Comment: oh okay, thank you that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

As JB King added, the numbers $>5$ do not include $5$. This means only $\frac{4}{10}$ of the numbers satisfy the condition. This means the other two choices have a $\frac{6}{10}$ probability and the last thing we have to multiply by is the number of ways to choose $1$ digit $>5$ out of $3$ $$\frac{4}{10}*\frac{6}{10}*\frac{6}{10}*\binom{3}{1}=.432$$